# How to handle BackPressed key of for Fragment by custom?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my android App, I have used fragment ,But for handling back key I have got problem ,
My structure is,

Its user account structure, in that,

1)Main Wall=> In that sub fragment->another fragment -> another fragment

2)When I click one button (Friends wall button )which is on this screen ,
then, open another wall which is same like main wall .

3)From main wall you will go another next screen.

I have maintain Stack of fragment for taking back, when back key pressed. Its works for Main wall  ,
But for back from friends wall to user wall its handling is goes difficult ,

Please give me any clue or suggestion for handling such condition.
,Now I handle B

Comment: try manually adding the transaction to backstack

Comment: Yes ,I handling it manually ,but there are my User Wall from this I can go next friends wall from last windows &  so on. But when I come back i want replace User Wall with last window from which we have goes to next screen. Its not possible by my end thts why I have asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the right way to do it using up button in the actionBar as in the screenshot below:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

[image: android backstack]

Comment: My implementation not this way  I have handle back pressed on Back key, Which is handle by OnBackPressed() method.

Comment: I would take a look at the following guide before continuing to develop: `http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html`

Comment: please consider accepting this answer if it has helped you :)